# Merge items from two arrays into a third array with a column subtracting the second index from the first

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to create arrayThree from arrayOne and arrayTwo. `Score` is the `index` of `arrayTwo` minus the `index` of `arrayOne`.

```
var arrayOne = [{ "Name" : "Blue" },
                { "Name" : "Pink" },
                { "Name" : "Green" },
                { "Name" : "Red" },
                { "Name" : "Yellow" }]
var arrayTwo = [{ "Name" : "Pink" },
                { "Name" : "Blue" },
                { "Name" : "Green" },
                { "Name" : "Red" },
                { "Name" : "Black" }]

var arrayThree = [{ "Name" : "Pink", "Score" : -1 },
                  { "Name" : "Blue", "Score" : 1 },
                  { "Name" : "Green", "Score" : 0 },
                  { "Name" : "Red", "Score" : 0 },
                  { "Name" : "Black", "Score" : 4 },
                  { "Name" : "Yellow", "Score" : -4 }]
```

I've tried to achieve this using `compareArrays` without success.

This is the closest I've got:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrayTwo, function (item) {
    arrayThree.push({ "Name": item, "Score": arrayOne.indexOf(item) })
}
```

**Update:**

Based on the comments, I've abandoned knockout functions and come up with the following solution. It's pretty ugly - I just wanted to get something working for now. Any optimisation suggestions are welcome:

```
$.map(arrayTwo , function (obj, index) {
    var oldindex = arrayOne.indexOf(obj);
    if (oldindex < 0) {
        arrayThree.push({ "Name": obj, "Score": Math.abs(5 - index) })
    } else {
         arrayThree.push({ "Name": obj, "Score": Math.abs(5 - index) - Math.abs(5 - oldindex) })
    }
})
$.map(arrayOne, function (obj, index) {
    var oldindex = arrayTwo.indexOf(obj);
    if (oldindex < 0) {
        arrayThree.push({ "Name": obj, "Score": Math.abs(5 - index) * -1 })
    }
})
```

Comment: Those don't look like arrays to me.

Comment: Repeat after me, "knockout is not a querying library." You are trying to perform a query, knockout is not something you should be using to do this. Use one that is built for this sort of task like [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) or something.

Comment: Jeff's right, knockout's `arrayForEach` is a convenience method mainly useful for `observableArray`s, use VanillaJS or a linq-like library for what you need (you have plain JS arrays there...). However, in addition to that: your question is rather unclear. You should be specific about your requirements (under the ones stated "Yellow" shouldn't be in the result array, or at least not with -4), and you haven't told us what the specific problem is with your code.

Comment: Comments noted. Question updated.

Comment: If you want the arrayThree to update whenever arrayOne or arrayTwo changes, you could use knockout for this; but it's not clear that's what you actually are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your example not working as expected. See [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvouf4uv/)
I can propose next solution:

```
function merge(arrayOne, arrayTwo, outputArray, inverseSum)
{
    for (var index =0, len=arrayOne.length;index<len;index++)
    {
        var name = arrayOne.shift().Name;
        var indexTwo = getIndexByName(arrayTwo, name);
        if (inverseSum || !getIndexByName(outputArray, name)[1])
        {
           var score = (inverseSum ? 1 : -1) * (indexTwo[0] - index)
           outputArray.push({"Name" : name, "Score" : score});
        }
    }
}


function getIndexByName(arr, name)
{
   for (var i=0, len=arr.length;i<len;i++)
   {
      if (arr[i].Name === name)
      {
          return [i, true];
      }
   }
   return [0, false];
}



function mergeArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, outputArray)
{
   merge(arrayOne, arrayTwo, outputArray, true);
   merge(arrayTwo, arrayOne, outputArray, false);
}
```

Usage:

```
mergeArrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree);
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7kpguuk/)